# How to route inside embedded component?

Tags: javascript, json, sapui5

I am developing a sample sapui5 app, which embeds another sapui5 app, as a component. I have already managed to load the component and display its root view content, but here comes the problem with routing. While routers for both apps - main and nested - work separately quite well, I simply cannot make them cooperate.
The routing in `manifest.json` defined in main app contains:

```
"config":{
            "routerClass":"sap.m.routing.Router",
            "viewType":"XML",
            "viewPath":"sample.main.view.detailPages",
            "controlId":"app",
            "controlAggregation":"detailPages",
            "clearTarget":false,
            "transition":"slide",
            "bypassed":{
                "target":["home","menu"]
            }               
        },
"routes":[
    {
        "pattern":"",
        "name":"appHome",
        "target":["home","menu"]
    },
    {
        "pattern":"ExternalApp",
        "name":"externalApp",
        "target":["externalApp","menu"]
    }],
"targets":{
    "home":{
        "viewName":"Home",
        "viewLevel":1
    },
    "menu":{
        "viewPath":"sample.main.view.masterPages",
        "viewName":"menu",
        "viewLevel":1,
        "controlAggregation":"masterPages"
    },
    "externalApp":{
        "viewName":"ExternalApp",
        "viewLevel":2
    }
}
```

Routing in `manifest.json` defined for embedded app contains:

```
        "config":{
            "routerClass":"sap.m.routing.Router",
            "viewType":"XML",
            "viewPath":"some.sample.view",
            "controlId":"EmbeddedApp",
            "controlAggregation":"pages",
            "clearTarget":false,
            "transition":"slide",
            "bypassed":{
                "target":"home"
            }
        },
        "routes":[
            {
                "name": "home",
                "pattern" : "",
                "target": "home"
            },
            {
                "name":"toPage2",
                "pattern":"page2",
                "target":"next"
            }
        ],
        "targets":{
            "home":{
                "viewName": "App",
                "viewLevel":1
            },
            "next":{
                "viewName": "Page2",
                "viewLevel":2
            }
        }
```

When I navigate in main app to the view, where the emedded app exsits, i see properly the root view (with url `#/ExternalApp`).
When I navigate in the embedded app with `navTo("toPage2")` I get no errors in console (so the router is implemented correctly), but instead of getting url hash `#/ExternalApp/page2`, I simply get `#/page2`. This leads to unrecognized pattern in main app and getting bypassed.

The question is - what is the right way to acheive routing inside the app embedded as a component? I suppose there should be some changes in the main app `manifest.json`, or some additional parameters should be passed to component, but I couldn't find any useful information.

Edit1:
What I found so far - the `Route` object has an attribute called `parent`, where I can declare path to container's object. When this attribute is filled, the external app's route patterns are automatically prefixed with appropriate parent's path. Not the best solution (external app still needs some *a priori* information about container app), but at least the patterns don't have to be manually rewritten in case of changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get both routers functional, you'll harmonize the routing pattern, e.g.:

In the container app:

```
"externalApp":{
    "viewName":"ExternalApp/:appspecific:",
    "viewLevel":2
}
```

And in the external app:

```
"next":{
    "viewName": "ExternalApp/Page2",
    "viewLevel":2
}
```

Comment: Your solution will probably work well, but I can't make any hard-coded prefixes in external app.

Comment: How so? It is quite easy to extend Fiori apps...  If that's not going to work, you may need to change the master app and see if you can turn it into something that works similar to the Fiori Launchpad. It would be my starting point to study the routing and componentisation concept in the launchpad to leverage them in my own app. Sounds like a tough cookie though, so good luck!